# print only part of JSON string

Tags: php, json

I need a PHP way to show only store_name in PHP

I have tried the following with no success

```
    <?php
require_once("admin/system/core.php");
$fetch = new server();
$fetch->connect();
$store = $fetch->getstore("movies");

print $store;
?>
```

the JSON looks like this
`[{"_id":{"$id":"4f67da1538fc5d7347000000"},"store_name":"movies","categories":{"name":"hoyts","products":{"name":"GoldClass","Price":"12.00","CashBack":"2.00"}}}]`

Comment: Have you tried, you know, parsing it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the returned value is json string. So you have to `decode` it from string to an `object` with `json_decode` function

```
$store = $fetch->getstore("movies");
$data  = json_decode($store);

foreach($data as $d) {
    echo $d->store_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your array will be

```
$array = array('id'=>'4f67da1538fc5d7347000000',
        'store_name'=>'movies');
echo $json = json_encode($array);
```

it echo's

```
{"id":"4f67da1538fc5d7347000000","store_name":"movies"}
```

then you can use

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->store_name;
```

which echo's `movies`